# Parsed Json array and object Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a json api to work with, I've already managed to extract part of the data, but I can't find the solution for array and object, how to extract and read this information in Flutter.

My Json:

```
    [
{
n_id: ""
n_datahora: ""
n_datahora_completo: ""
n_imagem: ""
n_uri: ""
n_titulo: ""
c_link: ""
n_autor: ""
n_links: {
1: {
link_tipo: "PDF",
link_titulo: "",
link: "test.pdf"
}
}
}
]
```

My Parsed json in Flutter, works, but i have no idea how parse array and object:

```
class ParseNoticias {
  String n_titulo;
  String n_descricao;
  String n_conteudo;
  String n_datahora_completo;
  String c_link;
  String n_autor;
  String n_imagem;
      
  ParseNoticias({
    String n_titulo,
    String n_descricao,
    String n_conteudo,
    String c_link,
    String n_data_hora_completo,
    String n_autor,
    String n_imagem,
    
  }) {
    this.n_titulo = n_titulo;
    this.c_link = c_link;
    this.n_descricao = n_descricao;
    this.n_conteudo = n_conteudo;
    this.n_datahora_completo = n_datahora_completo;
    this.n_autor = n_autor;
    this.n_imagem = n_imagem;
      }

  ParseNoticias.fromJson(Map json)
      : n_titulo = json['n_titulo'],
        n_descricao = json['n_descricao'],
        n_conteudo = json['n_conteudo'],
        c_link = json['c_link'],
        n_autor = json['n_autor'],
        n_datahora_completo = json['n_datahora_completo'],
        n_imagem = json['n_imagem'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "n_titulo": n_titulo,
        "n_descricao": n_descricao,
        "n_conteudo": n_conteudo,
        "n_autor": n_autor,
        "c_link": c_link,
        "n_datahora_completo": n_datahora_completo,
        "n_imagem": n_imagem,
         };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can use `Map<String, NLink> nLinks;` 
Step 2: You can parse with `parseNoticiasFromJson`, see full code below
Step 3: You can show data with `ListView.builder` and `Column` use `for` syntax

code snippet

```
Map<String, NLink> nLinks;
...
class NLink {
  NLink({
    this.linkTipo,
    this.linkTitulo,
    this.link,
  });
  
return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          for (var element
                              in snapshot.data[index].nLinks.keys)
                            Text(
                                " ${element} ${snapshot.data[index].nLinks[element].link}")
                        ],
                      );
                    });
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

List<ParseNoticias> parseNoticiasFromJson(String str) =>
    List<ParseNoticias>.from(
        json.decode(str).map((x) => ParseNoticias.fromJson(x)));

String parseNoticiasToJson(List<ParseNoticias> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class ParseNoticias {
  ParseNoticias({
    this.nId,
    this.nDatahora,
    this.nDatahoraCompleto,
    this.nImagem,
    this.nUri,
    this.nTitulo,
    this.cLink,
    this.nAutor,
    this.nLinks,
  });

  String nId;
  String nDatahora;
  String nDatahoraCompleto;
  String nImagem;
  String nUri;
  String nTitulo;
  String cLink;
  String nAutor;
  Map<String, NLink> nLinks;

  factory ParseNoticias.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ParseNoticias(
        nId: json["n_id"],
        nDatahora: json["n_datahora"],
        nDatahoraCompleto: json["n_datahora_completo"],
        nImagem: json["n_imagem"],
        nUri: json["n_uri"],
        nTitulo: json["n_titulo"],
        cLink: json["c_link"],
        nAutor: json["n_autor"],
        nLinks: Map.from(json["n_links"])
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, NLink>(k, NLink.fromJson(v))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "n_id": nId,
        "n_datahora": nDatahora,
        "n_datahora_completo": nDatahoraCompleto,
        "n_imagem": nImagem,
        "n_uri": nUri,
        "n_titulo": nTitulo,
        "c_link": cLink,
        "n_autor": nAutor,
        "n_links": Map.from(nLinks)
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      };
}

class NLink {
  NLink({
    this.linkTipo,
    this.linkTitulo,
    this.link,
  });

  String linkTipo;
  String linkTitulo;
  String link;

  factory NLink.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => NLink(
        linkTipo: json["link_tipo"],
        linkTitulo: json["link_titulo"],
        link: json["link"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "link_tipo": linkTipo,
        "link_titulo": linkTitulo,
        "link": link,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<ParseNoticias>> _future;

  Future<List<ParseNoticias>> _getRecords() async {
    /*var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull("url"),
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "**********",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        });
*/
    String jsonString = '''
    [
{
"n_id": "",
"n_datahora": "",
"n_datahora_completo": "",
"n_imagem": "",
"n_uri": "",
"n_titulo": "",
"c_link": "",
"n_autor": "",
"n_links": {
"1": {
"link_tipo": "PDF",
"link_titulo": "",
"link": "test1.pdf"
},
"2": {
"link_tipo": "PDF",
"link_titulo": "",
"link": "test2.pdf"
}
}
}
]
    ''';

    var response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return parseNoticiasFromJson(jsonString);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = _getRecords();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ParseNoticias>> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              for (var element
                                  in snapshot.data[index].nLinks.keys)
                                Text(
                                    " ${element} ${snapshot.data[index].nLinks[element].link}")
                            ],
                          );
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```